# AWS Connecting 2 regions

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, routing, ipsec

I've seen ways of connecting 2 regions to be a private network using AMI's but is there not a way to do this via VPC or DirectConnect.

At the minute we have:

- eu-west-1 (11 servers) on 172.16.0.0/16
- ap-southeast-2 (currently 1 server) on 172.31.0.0/16

I would have thought AWS had something in place to link regions but from a lot of Google yesterday, I've only found ways using linux systems to route the traffic. I'm fine with that if it's the only way, but part of me thinks there must be another simpler way?

Regards

Liam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't really overlooking anything.  There is no built-in way to connect VPCs together across regions.

At least, not yet.

One other option... if you have a physical data center and an appropriate VPN device there, you can use the hardware VPN capability of VPC to build tunnels from each region into that central device, then hairpin the traffic through that device, interconnecting the regions externally through back-to-back tunnels across the Internet, hub-and-spoke.

It's arguably more simple than using instances, since redundancy and route propagation among the availability zones on the AWS side is fully handled by the VPC infrastructure, but has costs in transport, latency, and is a potential single point of failure.

Comment: Hi Michael, Glad I'm not overlooking anything as I've been feeling totally useless not being able to work it out. That's interesting about using an external centre as we're part of a college and already connect to a VPC in Ireland, so if I got our collect to connect to the Australian one too, then the translation could be done at our college (2x 1gbps lines). The only thing the connection will really be used for is AD communication and a few powershell commands so shouldn't be an issue connecting Ireland to Australia via England. Thank you for your advice and ideas! :-)